# Why can we not vote to Close a question while viewing an Edit to it?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, vote-to-close

Sometimes, when an off-topic question is edited, it really should be closed instead, so why is there no option to cast a Close vote as well as all the other options?

Currently, I have to open the question in a new tab, then hit Skip before switching over to the other tab and casting my Close vote.

Wouldn't it be more expedient to be able to cast a Close vote and heading off to the next proposed edit instead of having to make a detour like we have to at present?

Granted, it isn't a common occurrence, but when it does happen, such an option would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

This seems unnecessary to me. Why hit Edit before actually reading the post and determining if it could stay.

In my opinion, those two options, Edit and Close, are not to be combined. You either edit or vote to close.

Adding this would only unnecessarily clutter the user interface.

Comment: True, we also can't vote and think not event comment from the suggested edits review.

Comment: What about the people who have proposed edits to off-topic questions? I didn't propose the edit, but it did show up in the proposed edits queue.

Comment: The suggested edit review queue is not meant for that. Its sole purpose is determining the usefulness of the edit.